# PDFtron "Value does not fall within the expected range." exception thrown when loading pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp, document, pdftron

I get the exception  `{"Value does not fall within the expected range."}` when I try to add a new pdf document into the view. And in the view, there are two pdf documents to load. One is loaded and the other throws this exception when loading.

Here is the c# code.

```
                       (this.DataContext as ViewerPageViewModel).Activate();
                       (this.DataContext as ViewerPageViewModel).OpenDoc(pdfDoc);
                       PDFViewCtrlBorder.Child = (this.DataContext as ViewerPageViewModel).PDFViewCtrl;
```

Here is the XAML code.

```
                                <Grid
                                x:Name="PaperGrid"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Background="{StaticResource WhiteBackgroundBrush}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Border x:Name="PDFViewCtrlBorder" >
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Border Child="{Binding}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a generic exception when setting an `UIElement` property with an invalid value.

Could you please share more information regarding the exception and perhaps a sample project so I can better understand it?

Also, if you are trying to open 2 PDFs on the same View, I would make sure to proper use binding to both `PDFViewCtrl` properties in your ViewModel and not try to set them on `Load` event or code-behind.

```
<Border x:Name="PDFViewCtrlBorder" >
     <Grid>
           <Border Child="{Binding PDFViewCtrl}" />
     </Grid>
</Border>
```

You can also take a look at our UWP samples repository which has a `PDFCompare` sample project which loads 2 PDFs on the view
https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-uwp-samples

You can also contact us on https://www.pdftron.com/company/contact-us/. From there we can provide you with one-on-one support and help you with a solution for your use case.

Kind regards,
Robson